# how to declare global variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am actually learning phase in python and I didn't get the help from google as well about it so guys please help me about global variable on specific requirement.

I use python 3.5 in ubuntu OS 16.04 and I have to declare a global variable in one file and initialise with a default value and import that into another python file in the same package but when to declare that and import that I get the following error in that file where import the global variable:

> AttributeError: module 'App.views' has no attribute 'request_dict'

Don't worry, I have code as well which is given below:

views.py:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

request_dict = OrderedDict()

def hello():
    print("hello from views file")
```

task.py:

```
from . import views

def addQueueTask():
    print('from task.py: ', views.request_dict)
```

Comment: Please add your folder/file structure.

Comment: You are using `Django` framework ?

Comment: what does `print(views.__file__)` give you?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Do you have both `views.py` and `task.py` inside of the same package (that is, a directory with a `__init__.py` file)?

Comment: Just what juanpa.arrivillaga says - obviously, "views" does not resolve to what you expect.

Comment: actually I get the error as : ImportError: cannot import name 'request_dict'
 when I use from .views import request_dict

Comment: Then please answer the question of juanpa.arrivillaga: "what does print(views.__file__) give you?". You might import a diffferent `view` module than you expect.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, print(views.__file__) gives right result i.e., /home/anita/Documents/HelloProject/HelloApp/views.py but then why gives request_dict is undefined in tasks.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing a file that is just a functions file for example:
funtions.py:

```
p = print
i = input
```

then move that file to the python installation folder. Where the python shell and idle are located. Then in any other file you can do:

```
from functions import p
p('hi')
```

then this code will return 'hi'

Comment: Thanks Zone for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a gloabl variable by using 'global' keyword before the name of a variable name

Answer (score -1):

```
from views import *
```

will import all objects and methods from `views`. However it generally something you [shouldn't do](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import)

Please consider

```
from views import request_dict
```

to only import the variable(s) you need and avoid polluting your namespace.

Comment: This will NOT solve the problem. If the name "request_dict" is not defined in whatever "views" resolves to, it's not defined, period.

Comment: When I use second one then I get following error:
ImportError: No module named 'views'. I don't know why